# Time series dataset where historical values are updated

Tags: data-request, time-series

I am looking for a time series dataset where the historical values changed through updated reports.  The data would be reported on some regular frequency, and the historical values (might) change with different reporting dates.  I am flexible as to the frequency of either the reporting or the actual data.  An example for what I am looking for is the below (fictional) data (does not have to be medical):

**Cases of Disease X by diagnosis date:**

Data reported on January 10th

January 5th: 23

January 6th: 12

January 7th: 14

January 8th: 16

January 9th: 10

January 10th: 2

Data reported on January 11th

January 5th: 24

January 6th: 15

January 7th: 18

January 8th: 20

January 9th: 21

January 10th: 22

Data reported on January 12th

January 5th: 24

January 6th: 16

January 7th: 18

January 8th: 23

January 9th: 24

January 10th: 29